# XMMATRIX and formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligneD

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, directx

I've tried migitating my old DirectX code to a newer one in Visual Studio 2013.

In Scene.cpp I have the function

`void AddInstance(Instance aInstance);`

Which is just a push_back:

```
m_vecInstances.push_back(aInstance);
```

This gives an error saying:

```
Error   1   error C2719: 'aInstance': formal parameter with __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned
```

The reason is Instance.h member has `DirectX::XMMATRIX m_Orientation;` and I don't understand how to solve this.
I found answers saying  DirectX::XMFLOAT4X4 but I rather don't

I'm guessing I could swap out std::vector but I think that also would just be walking around the problem.

Any answer that solves my problem would make my day <3

Comment: what is the type `Instance`?

Comment: Instance right now is just:
`class Instance
{
public:
 Instance();
 ~Instance();

 void Update();
 void Render();

private:

 DirectX::XMMATRIX m_Orientation;

};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DirectX::XMMATRIX __declspec(align('16')) won't be aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15245378/directxxmmatrix-declspecalign16-wont-be-aligned)

Although it's a slightly different situation than the answer to this question, the solution is the same - pass `Instance` by const reference into the AddInstance function.

```
void AddInstance(const Instance& aInstance);
```

Comment: It solves the error message indeed, however I'm getting an access violation doing this "sometimes" I guess that is because I'm using std::vector :(

Comment: I would think that it would cause a potential alignment exception on MMX/SSE instructions, not an access violation. Anyhow, if this answers the question, please accept it ;), and ask another question about the crash.